# QuickBlox: sample-message example. Can not receive message I send to my self

Tags: quickblox

I am intenting to run the sample-messages example. 
Change the credentials, and change also in MessageActivity, the userId, by the one that appears as mine in the admin panel for the application Id used.

I managed to compile it and run it. but I don't receive a message after sending it through button "Send notification for yourself".

It reaches qhe QBCallback onComplete function, after creating the event, but in the result variable it is said "No one can receive the message"

Answer (score 0):

You also have to update Google GCM settings in this sample

Refer to the http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android#Setup_GCM

1. Create and replace Consts.PROJECT_NUMBER
2. Crate API key and set it in the admin panel